# Error : length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent - but number of columns IS equal to number of columnnames

Tags: rbind

maybe you can help me with a small problem. I picked some data out of a bigger data file and combined those data in the end to a table. In the last line I want to put columnnames to that table. Before I put those columnnames to that table the length is = 115. But when I put the columnnames to that table the length is suddenly = 112 and the above mentioned error occurs. But I also counted the number of columnnames and there are 115. Maybe do you have clue what to do?

Thank you in advance and kind regards,
Julian

Code:

````
setwd("/home/julian/Schreibtisch/Test")

# Alle einzulesenden Daten
dirnames <- dir()

for(i in 1:length(dirnames)){
# Basis-Angaben
INSIST_basics_1 <- read.csv(dirnames[i])[ ,c('mouse.x', 'TN.Nr.')]
INSIST_basics_1 <- subset(INSIST_basics_1, mouse.x > 0)
INSIST_basics_1 <- INSIST_basics_1[,c('TN.Nr.')]
INSIST_basics_1 <- c(INSIST_basics_1)
INSIST_basics_1 <- rbind(INSIST_basics_1)

INSIST_basics_2 <- read.csv(dirnames[i])[ ,c('mouse.x', 'Termin')]
INSIST_basics_2 <- subset(INSIST_basics_2, mouse.x > 0)
INSIST_basics_2 <- INSIST_basics_2[,c('Termin')]
INSIST_basics_2 <- c(INSIST_basics_2)
INSIST_basics_2 <- rbind(INSIST_basics_2)

INSIST_basics_3 <- read.csv(dirnames[i])[ ,c('mouse.x', 'Zuweisung')]
INSIST_basics_3 <- subset(INSIST_basics_3, mouse.x > 0)
INSIST_basics_3 <- INSIST_basics_3[,c('Zuweisung')]
INSIST_basics_3 <- c(INSIST_basics_3)
INSIST_basics_3 <- rbind(INSIST_basics_3)

INSIST_basics <- c(INSIST_basics_1,INSIST_basics_2,INSIST_basics_3)
INSIST_basics <- rbind(INSIST_basics)

# VAS
INSIST_VAS <- read.csv(dirnames[i])[ ,c('Word', 'trials_4.thisIndex', 'trials_6.thisIndex', 'trials_10.thisIndex', 'trials_7.thisIndex', 'trials_8.thisIndex', 'slider.response')]
INSIST_VAS <- INSIST_VAS[-which(INSIST_VAS$Word == ""), ]

INSIST_VAS_1 <- subset(INSIST_VAS, trials_4.thisIndex >= 0)
INSIST_VAS_1 <- INSIST_VAS_1[order(INSIST_VAS_1$trials_4.thisIndex),]
INSIST_VAS_1 <- INSIST_VAS_1[,c('slider.response')]
INSIST_VAS_1 <- (INSIST_VAS_1 - 1) *100

INSIST_VAS_2 <- subset(INSIST_VAS, trials_6.thisIndex >= 0)
INSIST_VAS_2 <- INSIST_VAS_2[order(INSIST_VAS_2$trials_6.thisIndex),]
INSIST_VAS_2 <- INSIST_VAS_2[,c('slider.response')]
INSIST_VAS_2 <- (INSIST_VAS_2 - 1) *100

INSIST_VAS_3 <- subset(INSIST_VAS, trials_10.thisIndex >= 0)
INSIST_VAS_3 <- INSIST_VAS_3[order(INSIST_VAS_3$trials_10.thisIndex),]
INSIST_VAS_3 <- INSIST_VAS_3[,c('slider.response')]
INSIST_VAS_3 <- (INSIST_VAS_3 - 1) *100

INSIST_VAS_4 <- subset(INSIST_VAS, trials_7.thisIndex >= 0)
INSIST_VAS_4 <- INSIST_VAS_4[order(INSIST_VAS_4$trials_7.thisIndex),]
INSIST_VAS_4 <- INSIST_VAS_4[,c('slider.response')]
INSIST_VAS_4 <- (INSIST_VAS_4 - 1) *100

INSIST_VAS_5 <- subset(INSIST_VAS, trials_8.thisIndex >= 0)
INSIST_VAS_5 <- INSIST_VAS_5[order(INSIST_VAS_5$trials_8.thisIndex),]
INSIST_VAS_5 <- INSIST_VAS_5[,c('slider.response')]
INSIST_VAS_5 <- (INSIST_VAS_5 - 1) *100

INSIST_VAS_all <- c(INSIST_VAS_1,INSIST_VAS_2,INSIST_VAS_3,INSIST_VAS_4,INSIST_VAS_5)
INSIST_VAS_all <- rbind(INSIST_VAS_all)

# FB tDCS
INSIST_tDCS <- read.csv(dirnames[i])[ ,c('itemIndex','questions', 'ratings')]
INSIST_tDCS <- INSIST_tDCS[-which(INSIST_tDCS$questions == ""), ]
INSIST_tDCS <- INSIST_tDCS[,c('ratings')]
INSIST_tDCS <- c(INSIST_tDCS)
INSIST_tDCS <- rbind(INSIST_tDCS)

# FB Zustand
INSIST_Zustand <- read.csv(dirnames[i])[ ,c('questionText', 'trials_9.thisIndex', 'trials_13.thisIndex', 'trials_15.thisIndex', 'slider_13.response')] 
INSIST_Zustand <- INSIST_Zustand[-which(INSIST_Zustand$questionText == ""), ]

INSIST_Zustand_1 <- subset(INSIST_Zustand, trials_9.thisIndex >= 0)
INSIST_Zustand_1 <- INSIST_Zustand_1[order(INSIST_Zustand_1$trials_9.thisIndex),]
INSIST_Zustand_1 <- INSIST_Zustand_1[,c('slider_13.response')]
INSIST_Zustand_1 <- (INSIST_Zustand_1 - 1) *100

INSIST_Zustand_2 <- subset(INSIST_Zustand, trials_13.thisIndex >= 0)
INSIST_Zustand_2 <- INSIST_Zustand_2[order(INSIST_Zustand_2$trials_13.thisIndex),]
INSIST_Zustand_2 <- INSIST_Zustand_2[,c('slider_13.response')]
INSIST_Zustand_2 <- (INSIST_Zustand_2 - 1) *100

INSIST_Zustand_3 <- subset(INSIST_Zustand, trials_15.thisIndex >= 0)
INSIST_Zustand_3 <- INSIST_Zustand_3[order(INSIST_Zustand_3$trials_15.thisIndex),]
INSIST_Zustand_3 <- INSIST_Zustand_3[,c('slider_13.response')]
INSIST_Zustand_3 <- (INSIST_Zustand_3 - 1) *100

INSIST_Zustand_all <- c(INSIST_Zustand_1,INSIST_Zustand_2,INSIST_Zustand_3)
INSIST_Zustand_all <- rbind(INSIST_Zustand_all)

# Szenarien
INSIST_Szenarien <- read.csv(dirnames[i])[ ,c('scenario', 'trials_11.thisIndex', 'rating_2.response')] 
INSIST_Szenarien <- INSIST_Szenarien[-which(INSIST_Szenarien$scenario == ""), ]
INSIST_Szenarien <- INSIST_Szenarien[order(INSIST_Szenarien$trials_11.thisIndex),]
INSIST_Szenarien <- INSIST_Szenarien[,c('rating_2.response')]
INSIST_Szenarien <- c(INSIST_Szenarien)
INSIST_Szenarien <- rbind(INSIST_Szenarien)

# Alle Abschnitte zusammenfuehren
INSIST_tab <- c(INSIST_basics, INSIST_VAS_all, INSIST_tDCS, INSIST_Zustand_all, INSIST_Szenarien)
INSIST_tab <- rbind(INSIST_tab)


colnames(INSIST_tab) <- c( "TN_Nr", "Termin", "Zuweisung", "Hungrig_1", "Satt_1", "Durstig_1", "Aengstlich_1", "Froehlich_1", "Gestresst_1", "Schlaefrig_1", "Konzentriert_1", "Traurig_1", "Essen_generell_1", "Essen_suess_1", "Essen_herzhaft_1", "Hungrig_2", "Satt_2", "Durstig_2", "Aengstlich_2", "Froehlich_2", "Gestresst_2", "Schlaefrig_2", "Konzentriert_2", "Traurig_2", "Essen_generell_2", "Essen_suess_2", "Essen_herzhaft_2", "Hungrig_3", "Satt_3", "Durstig_3", "Aengstlich_3", "Froehlich_3", "Gestresst_3", "Schlaefrig_3", "Konzentriert_3", "Traurig_3", "Essen_generell_3", "Essen_suess_3", "Essen_herzhaft_3", "Hungrig_4", "Satt_4", "Durstig_4", "Aengstlich_4", "Froehlich_4", "Gestresst_4", "Schlaefrig_4", "Konzentriert_4", "Traurig_4", "Essen_generell_4", "Essen_suess_4", "Essen_herzhaft_4", "Hungrig_5", "Satt_5", "Durstig_5", "Aengstlich_5", "Froehlich_5", "Gestresst_5", "Schlaefrig_5", "Konzentriert_5", "Traurig_5", "Essen_generell_5", "Essen_suess_5", "Essen_herzhaft_5", "tDCS_Jucken_1", "tDCS_Schmerzen_1", "tDCS_Brennen_1", "tDCS_Waerme_1", "tDCS_Metall_1", "tDCS_Ermuedung_1", "tDCS_Kopf_1", "tDCS_Jucken_2", "tDCS_Schmerzen_2", "tDCS_Brennen_2", "tDCS_Waerme_2", "tDCS_Metall_2", "tDCS_Ermuedung_2", "tDCS_Kopf_2","tDCS_Jucken_3", "tDCS_Schmerzen_3", "tDCS_Brennen_3", "tDCS_Waerme_3", "tDCS_Metall_3", "tDCS_Ermuedung_3", "tDCS_Kopf_3", 'Zustand_Herr_1', 'Zustand_kontrollieren_1', 'Zustand_Versuchungen_1', 'Zustand_Stimmung_1', 'Zustand_Druck_1', 'Zustand_Kontrolle_1', 'Zustand_willensstark_1', 'Zustand_erschrocken_1', 'Zustand_ueberrascht_1', 'Zustand_Herr_2', 'Zustand_kontrollieren_2', 'Zustand_Versuchungen_2', 'Zustand_Stimmung_2', 'Zustand_Druck_2', 'Zustand_Kontrolle_2', 'Zustand_willensstark_2', 'Zustand_erschrocken_2', 'Zustand_ueberrascht_2','Zustand_Herr_3', 'Zustand_kontrollieren_3', 'Zustand_Versuchungen_3', 'Zustand_Stimmung_3', 'Zustand_Druck_3', 'Zustand_Kontrolle_3', 'Zustand_willensstark_3', 'Zustand_erschrocken_3', 'Zustand_ueberrascht_3','Kino', 'Pralinen', 'Zuhause', 'Weihnachtsessen' ) # Spaltennamen
}```
````